# check if row of time ranges overlap with other rows using M in power Query

Tags: powerquery, overlap, m

Please I need help, as I have a below table for emp_ID which has an activity with a start/end timestamp, in some cases, these timestamps are overlapped e.g. the first 2 rows and the second 2 rows with each other, how do keep one row based on the condition (greatest duration on the same day for the same employee) for the times that overlapped.

```
|Employee ID|Work Type| Duration (h)|Start TimeStamp |End TimeStamp  |Date     |
|-----------+---------+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------|
|2531       |(OJT)    | 4.97        |12/8/2022 7:02  |12/8/2022 12:00|12/8/2022|
|2531       |(OJT)    | 4.95        |12/8/2022 7:03  |12/8/2022 12:00|12/8/2022|
|2531       |(Idel)   | 2.50        |12/8/2022 12:30 |12/8/2022 15:00|12/8/2022|
|2531       |(Break)  | 0.50        |12/8/2022 12:00 |12/8/2022 12:30|12/8/2022|
```

the expected result is to add a flag (Yes/No) beside the first and third rows by adding a custom column that I can use to filter.

```
|Employee ID|Work Type| Duration (h)|Start TimeStamp |End TimeStamp  |Date     |Keep Row|
|-----------+---------+-------------+----------------+---------------+---------+--------|
|2531       |(OJT)    | 4.97        |12/8/2022 7:02  |12/8/2022 12:00|12/8/2022|Yes     |
|2531       |(OJT)    | 4.95        |12/8/2022 7:03  |12/8/2022 12:00|12/8/2022|No      |
|2531       |(Idel)   | 2.50        |12/8/2022 12:30 |12/8/2022 15:00|12/8/2022|Yes     |
|2531       |(Break)  | 0.50        |12/8/2022 12:00 |12/8/2022 12:30|12/8/2022|No      |
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic that dictates which rows should be flagged?

Comment: The logic includes that if there are more rows their start/end time are overlapped (on the same day for the same employee), the flag ```Yes``` will be added beside the greatest duration of these rows, e.g in the first 2 rows; the second row is overlapped with the first one and the first row has the greatest duration, so the flag ```Yes``` placed beside it.

Comment: Are we only ever comparing 2 rows at a time? Or using the Work type somehow? If I have 3 rows with start/end times of 8am-3pm, 2pm-6pm, and 3pm-10pm then 2pm-6pm overlaps with both row 8am-3pm and 3pm-10pm what do you compare the 2-6pm to?

Comment: @horseyride, we didn't take the work type into consideration, you are right and the count of rows is not fixed to be 2 rows only it could be 3 or more. we could set a condition for overlapping to be: if the rows start on the same day/hour only. so for the mentioned example we will keep all with flag ```No```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

See if this works for you.  It groups by [Employee ID, Work Type, Date,  Starting Hour] and marks those rows with the highest duration. Recodes start time hour for rows that are within another row's time period so they can be grouped

[image]

| Employee ID | Work Type | Duration | Start Time Stamp | End Time Stamp | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.15 | 12/08/22 07:05 | 12/08/22 10:35 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.04 | 12/08/22 08:05 | 12/08/22 09:00 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.02 | 12/08/22 07:15 | 12/08/22 07:50 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.02 | 12/08/22 07:05 | 12/08/22 07:39 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.07 | 12/08/22 08:05 | 12/08/22 09:50 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.11 | 12/08/22 08:15 | 12/08/22 11:00 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | IDEL | 0.00 | 12/08/22 06:05 | 12/08/22 06:10 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | IDEL | 0.02 | 12/08/22 07:05 | 12/08/22 07:39 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | IDEL | 0.07 | 12/08/22 08:05 | 12/08/22 09:50 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | IDEL | 0.03 | 12/08/22 08:15 | 12/08/22 09:00 | 12/08/22 |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.02 | 12/12/22 07:05 | 12/12/22 07:35 | 12/12/22 |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.02 | 12/12/22 07:05 | 12/12/22 07:39 | 12/12/22 |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.07 | 12/12/22 08:05 | 12/12/22 09:50 | 12/12/22 |
| 2531 | OJT | 0.03 | 12/12/22 08:15 | 12/12/22 09:00 | 12/12/22 |
| 2531 | IDEL | 0.00 | 12/12/22 06:05 | 12/12/22 06:10 | 12/12/22 |
| 2531 | IDEL | 0.02 | 12/12/22 07:05 | 12/12/22 07:39 | 12/12/22 |
| 2531 | IDEL | 0.07 | 12/12/22 08:05 | 12/12/22 09:50 | 12/12/22 |
| 2531 | IDEL | 0.03 | 12/12/22 08:15 | 12/12/22 09:00 | 12/12/22 |
| 2792 | OJT | 0.15 | 12/08/22 07:05 | 12/08/22 10:35 | 12/08/22 |
| 2792 | OJT | 0.02 | 12/08/22 07:05 | 12/08/22 07:39 | 12/08/22 |
| 2792 | OJT | 0.04 | 12/08/22 07:20 | 12/08/22 08:15 | 12/08/22 |
| 2792 | OJT | 0.08 | 12/08/22 08:05 | 12/08/22 10:00 | 12/08/22 |
| 2792 | OJT | 0.03 | 12/08/22 08:15 | 12/08/22 09:00 | 12/08/22 |
| 2792 | IDEL | 0.00 | 12/08/22 06:05 | 12/08/22 06:10 | 12/08/22 |
| 2792 | IDEL | 0.02 | 12/08/22 07:05 | 12/08/22 07:39 | 12/08/22 |
| 2792 | IDEL | 0.07 | 12/08/22 08:05 | 12/08/22 09:50 | 12/08/22 |
| 2792 | IDEL | 0.03 | 12/08/22 08:15 | 12/08/22 09:00 | 12/08/22 |

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{ {"Duration", type number}, {"Start Time Stamp", type datetime}, {"End Time Stamp", type datetime}, {"Date", type date}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "StartHour2", each Time.Hour([Start Time Stamp])),

// recode overlapped items start time
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1","StartHour",(x)=>List.Min(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each [Date]=x[Date] and [Employee ID]=x[Employee ID] and [Work Type]=x[Work Type] and [End Time Stamp]>=x[End Time Stamp] and [Start Time Stamp]<=x[Start Time Stamp])[StartHour2])),

#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Employee ID", "Work Type", "Date", "StartHour"}, {{"data", each 
     let a=List.Max (_[Duration]),
     b = Table.AddColumn(_,"Max", each if [Duration]=a then "max" else null)
 in b, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Duration", "Start Time Stamp", "End Time Stamp", "Index","Max"}, {"Duration", "Start Time Stamp", "End Time Stamp", "Index","Max"}),
#"Sorted Rows1" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded data",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows1",{"StartHour", "Index"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Start Time Stamp", type datetime}, {"End Time Stamp", type datetime}, {"Date", type date}})
in #"Changed Type1"
```

Comment: Could we add another condition of Strat/End that includes another one? e.g if the row is 7 am-3 pm and the other one is 9 Am-2 pm, So the first row's start/end included the second duration, and we need to get a flag beside the greatest (first row)

Comment: edited above answer. For additional help start new question with appropriate sample data that I don't have to retype. Thanks